# howto disable “Project > Build Automatically” in eclipse using ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, rad

I cannot find a task to do that.

I have tried:

```
<workspacePreferenceSet 
   preferencescope="instance"
   preferencequalifier="org.eclipse.core.resources"
   useeclipseprefs="true" 
   preferencename="description.autobuilding" 
   preferencevalue="false" />
```

Help needed.

Comment: This is not core Eclipse, I guess you are using IBM RSA/RAD?

Comment: Yes, I am using diferent IBM Rational tools.

Comment: I actually though this was core Eclipse. Does Eclipse offer a similar option to manipulate preferences?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use IBM RAD but the values you quote look correct.

However looking at the preference page in Eclipse that handles this setting (`IDEWorkspacePreferencePage`) there is special code to handle this preference which I guess the `workspacePreferenceSet` code does not know about.

Core Eclipse defines just a few `ant` tasks and nothing to change preferences.